# Facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My android app contain four activity 
 Namely 
1.MainActivityclass
 
2.ActivityTwo.class
3.ActivityThree.class
4.ActivityFour.class
I need to set facebook login option in 4th activity(ActivityFour.class)Facebook login option is  not working for this class 
But its working fine in MainActivity
I dono what's the problem
what to do to run facebook login activity in fourth class of my app 
see the below image in facebook app I mentioned the package name as well as activity name
Here I mentioned MainActivity,Is it correct or not ? or what to mention there 
[image: Facebook]

Here the code

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                //welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getId() + "!");
                welcome.setText("Loading...");

                String id=user.getId().toString();
                String name=user.getName().toString();
                Intent move2Inter=new Intent(ActivityFour.this ,ActivityThree.class);

                startActivity(move2Inter);

              }
              else
              {
                  TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                  //welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getId() + "!");
                  welcome.setText("one");
              }
            }
          }).executeAsync();
        }

 else
        {
          TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            //welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getId() + "!");
            welcome.setText("Two");
        }
      }
    });
```

Am getting ouput as **two in textview** so that the session is not opened

Comment: share logcat and your code

Comment: MainActvity is launcher activity for your app ?

Comment: run with debug button for logcat. did you add ActivityFour in manifest file ?

Comment: @haresh : yeah MainActivity

Comment: <activity android:name=".ActivityFour"            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity> @meysam

Comment: have you added your hash key for debug app ?

Comment: yes Haresh,the login option is working fine for Mainactivity other than MainActivity it doesn't work

Comment: @haresh:see the question now I updated with code